# Php (Synology) - From apache and command line, it get different result when executing external program

Tags: php, python, apache, synology

I use `exec()` / `shell_exec()` / `system()` to execute synology downloadstation cli program like below:

```
system("downloadstation 2>&1");
```

I use ssh to test php and it will return the correct result

```
$ php testworld.php
```

However I use website to test the result.
It will display

> Traceback (most recent call last): File "/usr/bin/downloadstation",
>   line 16, in import optparse, sys, os, datetime, time, re, pyPgSQL
>   ImportError: No module named pyPgSQL

Nas system have python2.4 and python2.7. And only python2.4 have PyPgSQL.

My system information is like below:

- System default "python" is python2.4.
- /usr/lib/ only have python2.7 folder
- Python2.4 path :　/volume1/@optware/lib/python2.4/
- PyPgSQL path : /volume1/@optware/lib/python2.4/site-packages/pyPgSQL

And I already test the normal program and it will return the same result:

```
system("ls");
```

How to fix this issue ?